# How to supply multiple lists to 'lapply'?

Tags: r, list, lapply, survey

My objective is to find svytotals of all the variables of a dataframe which contain the term 'INCOME'. I have to do this for multiple files. This is what I have done so far (thanks to stack overflow)-

Code-

```
 library(sqldf)
 library(survey)

 filenames=list.files(path=mypath1, glob2rx("*2014*rev*.txt") ) #doing it for the year 2014
 dl=lapply(filenames, function(x)   {read.csv.sql(paste(mypath1,file=x,sep = "/"),sep = "|",header = T,sql = "select * from file where SURVEY_STATUS = 'Accepted' AND DUPLICATE_RECORD = 'N'")}) 


  dj=lapply(dl, function(x) { x= cbind(x,total_pop=1,weight_country, 
                                 weight_state)})


  sdesign_country=lapply(dj, function(x) {svydesign(id=~TOWN_VILLAGE, strata=~STRATA, weight=~weight_country, data=x,nest=T)})
  sdesign_state=lapply(dj, function(x) {svydesign(id=~TOWN_VILLAGE, strata=~STRATA, weight=~weight_state, data=x,nest=T)})

 var_inc= lapply(dj, function(x) {grep("INCOME", colnames(x), value=TRUE)})
```

Now how do I calculate svytotals using survey package? It should look something like this-

```
 mylist[[1]]
 TOTAL_INCOME   INCOME_FROM_WAGES  .........
      x                  x1

 mylist[[2]]
 TOTAL_INCOME   INCOME_FROM_WAGES  .........
       y                   y1

  and so on
```

Comment: Is svy total just summing the the columns? Ie summing the vectors?

Comment: Yes. I want to calculate svy totals for all the columns in a file which contain the term 'Income'. A file includes income from 13 different sources. This is to be computed for multiple files.